# Generating sequence number in XSLT for parent child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to generate two types of sequence numbers for my input xml which contains parent and child elements repeatedly. see below for input

I have an input xml like:

```
<family>
 <parent>P1<parent>
 <child>C1<child>
</family>
<family>
 <parent>P1<parent>
 <child>C2<child>
</family>
<family>
 <parent>P2<parent>
 <child>C3<child>
</family>
<family>
 <parent>P2<parent>
 <child>C4<child>
</family>
<family>
 <parent>P2<parent>
 <child>C5<child>
</family>
```

My expected output is text file with content:

```
00001 C1 00001
00001 C2 00002
00002 C3 00001
00002 C4 00002
00002 C5 00003
```

for first sequence number based on parent, and second based on child.
I tried in my xsl using

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="family" group-by="child">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(),'00000')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="child"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(),'00000')"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

for the above xsl i'm getting same sequence number for both sides. is there any specific function or grouping concept to implement such that i can achieve the required output?
Please help me to go through this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your actual XML is well-formed, you need to use two `xsl:for-each-group` elements here. One for grouping by `parent`, and then nested one that groups the current-group by `child`

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="family" group-by="parent">
    <xsl:variable name="parentPos" select="format-number(position(),'00000')" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="child">
        <xsl:value-of select="$parentPos"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="child"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(),'00000')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Tim, i have one small doubt within this, how can i extract last child of the all parent nodes? eg: C2,C5

Comment: You could do something like `current-group()[last()]` in the outer `for-each-group` loop. If you can't get it to work, feel free to ask a whole new question here on SO. Thanks!

Comment: i got it, i've used an if condition position()=last() to get last elment in second loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to group by child at all. Isn't every child unique? If so, it should be sufficient to do:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="family" group-by="parent">
    <xsl:variable name="group-number" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/child">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($group-number,'00000')"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(),'00000')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>          
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

**Note**: it appears your input is already sorted by `parent`; in such case, you could use:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="family" group-adjacent="parent">
```

Comment: yes u are right, group by only child was a mistake. but thanks for "group-adjacent".